# Herança Java web Inheritance

Tags: java, herança

Tenho a herança a fazer abaixo e gostaria de saber como ficaria na main. Alguém aqui poderia ajudar?

Poderiam me dizer se tem problemas no mapeamento que fiz e como ficaria a mainTeste? Não consigo definir o valor da classe LancamentoDespesaParcelado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu uso:
1º o Eclipse; 
2º banco Oracle e para visualizar as tabelas do banco uso o oracle SQL Developer;
3º E no projeto vamos usar a estrategia de múltiplas tabelas com uso de Join;
Vou colocar o inicio das classes:

LANCAMENTO

```
 @Entity
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
 @DiscriminatorColumn(NAME="TIPO", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
 @Table(name="LANCAMENTO")
 public class Lancamento extends GenericModel{ ... }
```

LANCAMENTO_DESPESA

```
@Entity
public class LancamentoDespesa extends Lancamento{ ... }
```

LANCAMENTO_RECEITA

```
@Entity
public class LancamentoReceita extends Lancamento{ ... }
```

LANCAMENTO_DESPESA_PARCELADA

```
@Entity
public class LancamentoDespesa extends LancamentoDespesa{ 
    @Column(name = "PARCELA", nullable = true)
    private int numParcela;

    GET/SET...
}
```

Observações finais:
No SQL developer cria as tabelas de herança, mas também cria outras 4 tabelas com nomes:

```
HT_LANCAMENTO  
HT_LANCAMENTODESPESA  
HT_LANCAMENTORECEITA  
HT_LANCAMENTODESPESAPARCELADA
```

E todas tem no desenhozinho da tabela um quadradinho com x.

Não consigo por outra foto aqui se não colocaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, eu copiei o código e realizei as seguintes alterações para a geração de tabeles funcionar:

LANCAMENTO

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(NAME="TIPO", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="LANCAMENTO")
public class Lancamento extends GenericModel { ... }
```

LANCAMENTO_RECEITA

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class LancamentoReceita extends Lancamento { ... }
```

LANCAMENTO_DESPESA

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class LancamentoDespesa extends Lancamento { ... }
```

LANCAMENTO_DESPESA_PARCELADA

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
public class LancamentoDespesa extends LancamentoDespesa { 
    @Column(name = "PARCELA", nullable = true)
    private int numParcela;

    GET/SET...
}
```

Quando se usa `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` e `@DiscriminatorColumn`, é necessário também usar a anotação `@DiscriminatorValue` para definir o valor que será usado para distinguir o tipo da entidade concreta.

No meu exemplo eu mudei para `DiscriminatorType.INTEGER` pois usando o CHAR não funcionou com o Hibernate nos meus testes.

Comment: E como ficaria a main do teste unitario para lançar o LANCAMENTO? Como lanço as parcelas da classe LANCAMENTODESPESAPARCELADA?

Comment: Lancamento lancamento = new LancamentoDespesaParcelada();
service.save(lancamento);

Comment: Sim. Eu fiz isso, ok, mas em que momento eu defino as parcelas? intende... ai que fiquei perdido. Este sistema é para lançamentos financeiros de RECEITA ou DESPESA, e me corrija se estou errado... eu NÃO vou instanciar LANCAMENTO, eu sempre tenho que instanciar e escolher LANCAMENTO_DESPESA ou LANCAMENTO_RECEITA ou se for parcelado LANCAMENTO_DESPESA_PARCELADA, isso PQ vou ter tudo que tem LANCAMENTO e no caso se parcelado, tenho PARCELA... este é o raciocínio... desculpa se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Teste agora e é isso mesmo Roque. No SQL Developer na tabela LANCAMENTO tenho todos dados e na coluna TIPO tenho 3 (da tabela LANCAMENTODESPESAPARCELADA). E na tabela LANCAMENTODESPESAPARCELADA tenho o id do LANCAMENTO e mais o valor de parcelas da coluna PARCELA = 10.

Comment: Legal. Se tiver te ajudado, por favor marca a resposta como correta :)

Comment: Eu esqueci que por exemplo quando temos PESSOA e temos ESTAGIARIO e FUNCIONARIO que herdam de PESSOA, a gente nuca instancia PESSOA e sim ESTAGIARIO ou FUNCIONARIO. Ajudou sim!